Polygon feature with linestring attached or unattached
I used Python GDAL API to union multiple polygons into one single polygon for the CONUS 49 state boundary, and the result shows some artifacts below.
What could be the reason for this?
I also used the exterior ring to simplify the polygon, but there is still one line attached at the edge.


Slivers are slivers. They occur along all non-identical boundaries.

You can use SetPrecision on the result of the union with a GridSize ~10 times larger than the maximum sliver/gap width you want to clean.
This will have the following effects:

Coordinates will be rounded if the precision grid specified is less precise than the input geometry. Duplicated vertices will be dropped from lines and polygons.
Line and polygon geometries will become "empty" if all vertices are closer together than the grid size or if they become significantly narrower than the grid size.
Polygon rings that are too narrow will be removed, e.g. for your very narrow islands in the polygons
Spikes or sections in Polygons significantly narrower than grid_size after rounding the vertices will be removed, e.g. for the spike in your example.

